# Exclude a configuration when @WebMvcTest in Spring Boot 1.4

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc-test

I have a @SpringBootApplication class in `java/` directory(same package) and another @SpringBootApplication class in `test/` for mocking some auto-wired beans. There are several tests and which configuration is used varies from test to test.

And in a test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(RecApiServerController.class)
```

throws

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Found multiple @SpringBootConfiguration annotated classes [Generic bean: class [com.xxx.MockedTestConfig]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in file [/..direction.../target/test-classes/com/xxx/MockedTestConfig.class], Generic bean: class [com.xxx.MyApplication]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in file [/...direction.../target/classes/com/xxx/MyApplication.class]]
```

I just want to test routing of a controller.

How could I set a specific application configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have two `@SpringBootConfiguration` (`@SpringBootApplication`) in the same package. `@WebMvcTest` searches automatically the source of configuration for you (see [the doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-detecting-config)). You can have a special `@SpringBootConfiguration` (or application) in a nested package of your test if you want to tune things but you can't have two in the same package.

I am not sure the doc is very explicit about that so we should probably clarify it.

Anyway, a custom `@SpringBootApplication` and slicing is a bit weird. `@SpringMvcTest` already takes care of only enabling what is necessary. If you want to mock some beans, you should *not* define that in a `@SpringBootApplication`. A regular `@Configuration` that you import is fine. We also have `@MockBean` to automatically mock things for you.

Comment: I changed `MockedTestConfig.class` to regular @Configuration and add  `classes = { MyApplication.class, MockedTestConfig.class }` in @SpringBootTest, and all tests worked fine. They didn't before, so I changed it to @SpringBootApplication. I think the order in `classes` was wrong that time. Thank you. :)